# Java: how to pass session id for rest api call in api testing?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, selenium-webdriver, web-api-testing

For UI automation testing, I need to do REST Api calls, to get the response. I am passing session id into the HEADER by request.setheader, but I recieved response as :

```
{"result":{"success":false,"httpCode":200,"errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID","errorMessage":"Session ID not provided... Kindly Login !!"}}
```

I have tried displaying session id and it seems to be fine, What I don't understand is, why it is not been passed to the API. Below is the code:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getUrl);

            SessionId SessionId = ((FirefoxDriver)driver).getSessionId();
             request.setHeader("Cookie", SessionId.toString());
             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

               InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
               BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));
               if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=HttpStatus.SC_OK)
               {
                   throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
               }
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               String s;
               while(true )
               {
                   s = buf.readLine();
                   if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                       break;
                   sb.append(s);

               }
               buf.close();
               ips.close();
               System.out.println("After parsing: "+sb.toString());
```

Output:
After parsing: strong text

```
{"result":{"success":false,"httpCode":200,"errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID","errorMessage":"Session ID not provided... Kindly Login !!"}}
```

Comment: For UI testing you must not do api calls. Mock them. You can't rely on network for UI tests.

Comment: for few of test cases in my UI testing, I need the response from api's. This is the reason, basically for functionality testing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:
changed,

```
 request.setHeader("Cookie", SessionId.toString());
```

to

```
 request.setHeader("sessionId", SessionId.toString());
```

This was mentioned in the API document given by the API team.
Then the session ID is given as output from the previous API call, which needs to be passed in the subsequent API calls. I had no idea about this since I am new to API testing. Hope my answer helps someone in a similar situation!!